# Says function returns null even though data is passed?

Tags: jquery

When i try to sort this function out IN Jquery its saying formatvalues return is now i do not understand that when the item values are being passed ok

```
function GetViewData(data) {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Services/Configuration/ViewServices.asmx/GetIncidentViewData",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: OnViewDataLoaded,
    error: OnViewDataNodeLoadFailed
});
```

}

```
function OnViewDataLoaded(data, status) {
$('#viewpane-table > tbody').empty();
var members = data.d;
var loadedFirst = false;

var tablevalues = '<tr>';

$.each(data.d.Columns, function (index, value) {

    tablevalues += FormatValues(value);
});
tablevalues += '</tr>';


$('#viewpane-table  > tbody').append(tablevalues);
```

Format Values is this function

```
 function FormatValues(value) {
    return '<td><b>' + value + '</b></td>';
}
```

Error message

> Unhandled exception at line 25, column 9 in  init.js
>
> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: The value of the property 'FormatValues' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Comment: 1. This has nothing to do with C#. 2. Edit your question to include the exact error message.

Comment: What do you get when you console.log your data parameter in your onViewDataLoaded function? Also, where are you declaring your FormatValues function? Is it in the global scope?

Comment: @oliakaoil With in the same js file

Comment: @DavidBuckley Your error sounds to me like it doesn't think that function is defined, which implies that it can't find your function, even though it is technically declared somewhere, which is why I suggested there may be a scope issue.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that if you hard coded the 'value' in your function it would work...i.e.

```
FormatValues("hello world")
```

would return

```
<td><b>hello world</b></td>
```

as expected.

So the issue is most likely in the `$.each(data.d.Columns, function (index, value)` call.

Comment: correct their is something wrong with the the values